# Standard for specifying times that happened twice?

Tags: datetime, timezone

Given the discontinuity in timezones, is there a standard method of specifying which of two repeated clock times you are interested in? This came to my attention from a Java discussion "[Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)", that was recently brought up, but this is not isolated to strange events in China in the 1920's.

How do I tell you which 01:50 AM (EST) I am interested in on November 3rd this year? I know that I could use UTC, epoch time... but is there even a good way to ask a user which local time they are interested in?

Comment: The only way to disambiguate the two times is by specifying which time zone offset was in use — either explicitly with a number (UTC-05:00 vs UTC-04:00) or implicitly with an abbreviation (EST vs EDT), or with words like 'the first 01:50 am' or 'the second 01:50 am'. There really isn't any other way: the time 01:50 without any such qualification is (on that day) ambiguous.

Comment: Note that as it stands, this isn't really programming question. How you *really* specify this will depend on your development environment, such as programming language, libraries, if you are using a sane operating system or not, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tell you which 01:50 AM (EST) I am interested in on November 3rd this year?

By qualifying it as EST, you are already specifying that you mean "Eastern Standard Time" which is UTC-05:00.  That is the second instance of 1:50am.  The first instance occurred in "Eastern Daylight Time" (EDT) which is UTC-04:00.  Of course, had you just said "Eastern Time", then I wouldn't know which one you meant.

However - keep in mind that "EST" by itself is not unique.  I made a guess that you meant Eastern Standard Time in the USA - but you could have meant one of three different zones all called the same thing.  [See here for a list of time zone abbreviations.](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/)  Now it happens to be that all "EST" zones are in UTC-05:00, but that is just coincidence.  There are several zones that have the same name or abbreviation and have different offsets or different DST start/stop dates.

The "standard" you are looking for is part of ISO8601, which allows for dates and times to include an offset.  For example, the two points mentioned would be:

```
2013-11-03T01:50:00-04:00

2013-11-03T01:50:00-05:00
```

Keep in mind that the offset uniquely identifies the moment/instant in time - but it it does *not* uniquely identify a time zone.  There are several other time zones that use the -04:00 and -05:00 offsets at different times.  This point is often forgotten, because the offset is sometimes referred to as the "zone" erroneously.